# How can I deal with paired dataset in DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'source': [1000, 1000, 1001, 1001, 1002,1002], 'acceptability': [1,0,1,0,1,0], 'sentence': ['I do not know', 'I does not know', 'you are stupid', 'you is stupid', 'she is bad for python', 'she are bad for python']})
```

What I want to do is comparing two sentences which share same source. After splitting or merging(whatever..), I'd like to use Jaccard Similarity between two sentences.

I don't know how to make it done with loop.

Maybe the prototype is like this.

Source: 1000, acceptability: 1, sentence:

Source: 1000, acceptability: 0, sentence:

....

Source: 1001, acceptability: 1, sentence:

Source: 1001, acceptability: 0, sentence:

...

After splitting DataFrame with loop station, I hope to compare those pairs based on Jaccard Similarity.
If the pairs' similarity score is too low, I want to drop that pair from DataFrame.

I really need u guys help!!

Thx for helping me !!

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to use Jaccard Similarity between two sentences.

Let's define a function for the [Jaccard similarity coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) of a set list first:

```
def JaccSim(sets): return len(set.intersection(*sets))/len(set.union(*sets))
```

> comparing two sentences which share same source

We can use [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for splitting the DataFrame by *source* without the need for an explicit loop:

```
js = df.groupby('source').apply(lambda d: JaccSim(d['sentence'].str.split().apply(set)))
```

This converts the sentences of each source group to a list of sets of words and computes the similarity coefficient, giving:

```
source
1000    0.600000
1001    0.500000
1002    0.666667
dtype: float64
```

> If the pairs' similarity score is too low, I want to drop that pair from DataFrame.

Now to extract the rows with high enough similarity (e. g. at least 0.6) can be as easy as

```
df = df.set_index('source')[.6<=js]
```

However, this prints a `UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.` We can avoid that by instead using

```
df = df.set_index('source')[.6<=js[df['source']]]
```